# how to include the same relative php in different folder depth php?

Tags: php, zen-cart

how to include the same relative php in different folder depth php?
for some reason , I need to add a www/subam/index.php in my zencart website , and this php need to the www/includes/application_top.php , but if I require(../includes/application_top.php) ,it will go wrong . how to do?

```
<?php 
/* index.php */
require('includes/application_top.php');

/* subam/index.php */
// this will be wrong
require('../includes/application_top.php');
?>
```

Comment: using application_path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to set your include path

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..');
```

Answer (score 1):

always use physical full path then you won't have any problem:

php 5.3:

```
require(__DIR__ . '/lib/file.php');
```

if you need to go back from where you are use ../:

```
require(__DIR__ . '/../lib/file.php');
```

php 5.2 and lower:
replace `__DIR__` with `dirname(__FILE__)`

in your example:

```
/* index.php */
require(__DIR__ .  '/includes/application_top.php');

/* subam/index.php */
require(__DIR__ .  '/../includes/application_top.php');
```